# Software to convert a EXE to MSI

Tags: windows, gratis, file-converter

What's the best free tool to convert EXE to MSI? I'd like to convert X-lite installer.

The goal is to deploy X-lite with a GPO Policy.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for windows so I added the tag

Comment: Not to send you away, but until someone posts an answer, you may find [this helpful](http://serverfault.com/q/22313/217937)

Comment: ... or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854873/how-to-make-an-msi-that-simply-wraps-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Exe to MSI converter [exemsi](http://www.exemsi.com/) - there are both free and professional versions available but AFAIK the free version is quite full featured.